# strange ng-repeat behaviour with back button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this hidden input in my form

```
<input type="hidden" ng-repeat="dasBottle in bottles track by $index" value="{{ dasBottle.id }}" name="bottles[]" />
```

When a button gets clicked, the option currently selected in a select input gets added to the page:

```
$scope.bottles.push(bottle);
```

with the correct value and everything is fine.

```
<input type="hidden" ng-repeat="dasBottle in bottles track by $index" value="30" name="bottles[]" class="ng-scope">
```

The user can add as many of these as they wish and the value is correct every time.

However, if the user submits the form, but then presses the back button, the same process works, however each new hidden field has the value of the **first hidden input added before the form was first submitted**, in this case 30. The only way to get it back to normal is to refresh the page.

The scope variable does get set to an empty array when the controller is setup:

```
$scope.bottles = [];
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try `dasBottle in bottles track by dasBottle.id" instead.

Comment: That didn't work either :/

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? Once each name becomes unique: like `bottles[{{ $index }}]` problem disappears. But I do not know how good is it to put something inside brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You might explicitly add index to the array of data you want to form from your form:

```
bottles[{{ $index }}]
```

My colleagues on the backend side say that this doesn't change the way data arrives to them, but strange behaviour gets fixed.